# Get array key and structure data from an array with structure

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I've got an array that has a structure. Problem is that I can't output the array number and the structure data in the same loop, but if I have two different loops, the data will show without any errors.

The code below has two different loops showing how I can access the array  number and structure data separately.

How do you output the array number and structure data in the same loop?

Code can be tested here https://cffiddle.org/

```
<!--- Create new structure --->
<cfset structRe = StructNew() />

<!--- Add data to structure --->
<cfset structRe.id = "14">          
<cfset structRe.title = "Title">

<!--- Create new Array --->
<cfset arryRe = ArrayNew(1) />

<!--- Add structure to array --->
<cfset ArrayAppend(arryRe, structRe)>

<cfoutput>
    <cfdump var="#arryRe#" />
</cfoutput>

<!--- Loop to access structure --->
<cfloop array ="#arryRe#" index="i">

    <cfoutput>
    #i.id# #i.title# <br />
    </cfoutput>
  
</cfloop>

<!--- Loop to access array number --->
<cfloop array ="#arryRe#" item="item" index="i">

    <cfoutput>
    #i# <br />
    </cfoutput>
  
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying your code a bit, and adding local scope (assuming you're in a function), here's another way to do this, too:

```
<cfset local.arrayRe = [
    {"id": "14", "title": "Title Fourteen"}
    , {"id": "15", "title": "Title Fifteen"}
] />


<cfloop array="#local.arrayRe#" index="local.i" item="local.stItem">
    <cfoutput>
        Item ##: #local.i#, ID: #local.stItem.id#, Title: #local.stItem.title#<br />
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I've seen a new way of doing things.

Comment: Remember to encode your output with [`encodeForHtml`](https://cfdocs.org/encodeforhtml). That innocent `title` might cause you problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

```
<cfloop array ="#arryRe#" item="item" index="i">

    <cfoutput>
        #i# #item.id# #item.title#<br />
    </cfoutput>
  
</cfloop>
```